# How to make an HTTP/HTTPS request within a Node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, cpanel

I'm just starting to learn Node.js and right now, I'm trying to use a Node.js Application through cPanel to provide a JSON response when its app's URL is accessed.

When visiting the app's URL, it's evident that the Node.js server is working as it should. So after editing the main JS file, and restarting the Node.js app, changes are reflected when visiting the URL again.

My problem:
Within the function of `https.createServer( function (req, res) {});`, I want to make an HTTPS request to a PHP file elsewhere, which returns a JSON response. At the moment, I can't even get a response or error from any type of request with the PHP file.

```js
var https = require('https');
var server = https.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var message = "";
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });

    var options = {
        host: "mydomain.com",
        path: '/myPhpScript.php'
    };
    https.get(options, function(res) {
        var bodyChunks = [];
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            bodyChunks.push(chunk);
        }).on('end', function() {
            var body = Buffer.concat(bodyChunks);
            message += body;
        })
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        message += e;
    });
    res.end(message);
});
server.listen();
```

As you can see, `message` would be what's displayed to the browser window, but it's empty. Nothing appears when visiting the App URL. Is it possible to make an HTTPS request with a Node.js HTTPS server?

Note:
I've also tried with `native-request` and `axios` and have experienced the same issue.

Comment: What happens when you visit the php url from your browser? Does it return the content you want? Is this a problem with a http(s) request in node? Have you tried a other url, like `https://example.com`? In your server code you dont wait that the requests is completed, you send imediatly a empty message. Move `res.end()` inside the "end" event callback.

Comment: @Marc Thanks for the comment. The PHP URL returns what it's supposed to. res.end(message) is the third last line in my code. As I've played around with this server function, I'm able to make the response end with a message being displayed, just not particularly the JSON response that I should be getting from the PHP file.

Comment: Without any data/chunk what you want/need its hard to help you. (or real example). BTW. you set your response header to "text/plain" why not "application/json" ?

Comment: @Marc https://jarrenmorris.com/gamesense/r6_db/1.json for example. It doesn't really matter exactly what the JSON is, but I get the same result whether it's a php script that returns JSON, or an actual json file itself. With the current code I have, my browser is just saying Request Timeout. The response header is "text/plain" for now because I was using the message variable to output other information for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server code:

```js
var http = require('http');
var https = require("https");

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    let call = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        var options = {
            host: "jarrenmorris.com",
            port: 443,
            path: '/gamesense/r6_db/1.json'
        };

        https.get(options, function (res) {

            var bodyChunks = [];

            res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                bodyChunks.push(chunk);
            }).on('end', function () {
                resolve(Buffer.concat(bodyChunks));
            });

        }).on('error', function (e) {
            reject(e);
        });

    });


    call.then((data) => {

        // do something here with the successful request/json

        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });

        res.end(data);

    }).catch((err) => {

        // do something here with the failure request/json
        // res.write("ERROR:");
        res.end(err);

    });

});

server.listen(8081, "127.0.0.1", () => {
    console.log(`Server listen on ${server.address().address}:${server.address().port} `);
});
```

Response:

```
{"name":"tim","age":"42"}
```

First thing i noticed, while i tried to run your code was, you cant establish a connection to your node.js.

The reason for this was you use the `https` module, but didnt specify an certificates/keyfiles. Skip this, and work with `http` till you get the result you want.

Then i wrapped you https request to the external api/file in a promise.
This allows a simple chaining and better readability of the code.

When the promises resolves/fullfill, we answer the request on the http server with the data we received from the external request.

The `res.end` in your code (where you put it) made no sense, since you didnt wait for the external request to complete. Thats the reason why its nothing is shown in the browser window.